# Cannot pass json data to Ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

based on below code, i want to understand why i cannot call data from json (`json.projects[i].projName`) when i am calling it from ajax function?

```
var json = JSON.parse(data);

for (var i = 0; i < json.projects.length; i++) {  

alert(json.projects[i].projName); //will show correct data

    $.ajax({ url: epridlist, method: 'GET'}).then(function (datas) {
        alert(json.projects[i].projName) // this will fail. says not know projName, when projName existed in jason data
    });
}
```

Please help me understand. if i alert outside ajax function, result will show

Comment: I rolled back your question because your edit invalidated existing answers. If the answer answered your question, accept it. If you have followup questions, please ask a new question.

Comment: I did read the post, and I cannot relate it with my code. my data is from json array and the example just count i. whats the relation? this is so frustrating

Comment: in your edit... you said your problem was solved, and you had a new problem after adding a new inner loop, that's different. From what i saw of it before rolling back, it was completely unrelated to your original problem because you were properly using `let` to avoid the closure loop problem. [The new problem](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41835949/revisions) was likely a case of passing incorrect data.

Comment: it is correct data. and this isnt duplicated question.

Comment: Your original question is in fact a duplicate. Your new question is not, however, your new question invalidates your existing answers, and therefore cannot be edited into your original question.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle re-creating your "new" question with invalid object literal fixed. https://jsfiddle.net/kwmk52ca/1/

Comment: And, of course, the problem is because one of your... tasks don't have a taskName, instead it has a projName.

Comment: my task have taskName, and still your code not run good. your code in fiddle, i tested with my json file, still it gave me undefined value. i have ajax function between each for loop, and this increase my problems. Btw thanks for your kindness to help. I already submit new post on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of closure. The inner function in the Ajax success callback creates a closure and value of variable `i` is captured. The inner function contains a reference to the `i` variable.

After the loop executes, The value of `i` would be `json.projects.length` and when you try to access the `json.projects[json.projects.length]` you would get `undefined`.

To solve your problem you can try using the `let` variable instead of `var` which has a shorter scope as compared to the function scope.

You can refer to other approaches in this question: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

var json = JSON.parse(data);

```
for (let i = 0; i < json.projects.length; i++) {  

alert(json.projects[i].projName); //will show correct data

    $.ajax({ url: epridlist, method: 'GET'}).then(function (datas) {
        alert(json.projects[i].projName) // this will fail. says not know projName, when projName existed in jason data
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate your reply. Can you suggest to me, how can i access the data from (json.projects[i].projName) inside the Ajax?

Comment: It works very nice now... Thanks alot :)

Comment: Hi Agalo, the loop runs smoothly at first, but when i add another loop inside, it returns undefine value

Comment: Check the link i updated in the answer, it will provide you more options.

Comment: i dont understand how to related with my function. but thanks agalo

Comment: Inside the other function `json.projects[i].task_data[k].taskName`. if you are using the `i` then it will point to the last value of i; So, it is undefined. Are both functions different or one inside another ?

Comment: it is one inside another, because project contains array of task_data. one project can have many task_data